# extra space between two custom cells in tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is my app

[image]

As you see, there is a space there, between the first and the second cell.

i hit my head in the rock to find the error, and i couldn't

this is the contracts for the first cell

[image]

i give you **any information** that you want,

please help

#### Update

after matt suggested to use the debugger, i found this

[image]

as you see, the cell is longer (taller) than the content, i din't know how to fix it

Comment: Why don't you use View Debugging to find out what's going on in that space?

Comment: @matt Oh what is that? sounds something i should have already known

Comment: Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy.

Comment: @matt http://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbed.png all is disabled as you see

Comment: @matt okay now they are shown, but i didn't know how to fix it

Comment: What you found out is excellent info; well done.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all table view cells have the same height. If you don't like that, you can implement the table view delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to give particular rows of the table a different height.

It is also possible to let the cell dictate its height from the inside out by way of constraints.

Comment: `sizeToFit` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @Tim how can I apply this sizeToFit?

Comment: @matt how I can't set a specific high programatcailly. otherwise, it won't work on all devices, there should be something in the constrains right?

Comment: Why would the height of this one cell be different on different devices?